# How to use span_first? Or a different way to score based on first word?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to boost the result with a match on the first word.

So if I have
{ name: 'foo' }, { name: 'batz fitz' }

I could do:

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "match": {
        "name": "foo fitz"
      }
    }
  ],
  "should": [
    {
      "span_first": {
        "match": {
          "span_term": {
            "name": "foo fitz"
          }
        },
        "end": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}
}

But it didn't seem to change the score so I tried to run only the should clause, but it gives no results at all.

So how should I use this span_first?
Or is there another way to boost result with match on first word?

Answer (score 1):

For `span_first` you should set `end` equal to your query length.

If you want to match only on "foo" it might make sense to extract first word from the data on indexing and store in a separate field then use that field.

Comment: What do you mean query length? If it's not modified why do I even have option to change it?

Comment: If your query is "too Fitz" then you should set "end" to 8, as I understand

Comment: what "end" means, I thought it's word count. I am sending queries with JS so I can calculate some things before sending the queue but I need to understand what it is

Comment: No it's match position and looks like it needs both start and end position to be below `end`